# What is Animation Nodes addon used for?

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

What is Animation Nodes addon used for? Where can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Animation Nodes addon (AN) is a "Node based visual scripting system designed for motion graphics in Blender."

It allows the creation of procedural animations. Furthermore, it can achieve many effects that are otherwise only possible through programming.

To get a better impression of what is possible, check the showreels for [2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnlUhlkxQZU), [2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCghhlMOwRg) and [2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB8R_xPpaSc).

Download [Animation Nodes Addon](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases).

You can find the official documentation [here](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io). It also includes a list of most of the tutorials creators.

Check the official Blender Artists [thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350296-Addon-Animation-Nodes) where the community collaborate, share their work and provide information about AN.

Comment: Fairly Enough. Thanks Jacques for the nice answer, and the great addon!