# What are animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

So, I've come across this term while using other software as well. However, with respect to Blender, what are they? How does one use/access them and if possible could a simple animation be demonstrated using this?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/what-is-animation-nodes-addon-used-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an addon that adds a procedural node based modelling and animation tools and workflow to Blender.

You can learn more about it at the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)

From the official description

> Node based visual scripting system designed for motion graphics in Blender.