# Everything Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, experimental-features

A few years ago in blender community exploded an information that blender will make some game changing feature, they called Everything Nodes, but to this day, we have nothing more than one short video on YouTube..

Thoes anyone know, what's with this feature?

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

am.wernicki.eu

Comment: That is the Principled Shader. In the new version it also available for volumes. https://youtu.be/4H5W6C_Mbck

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76136/what-are-animation-nodes/76137#76137 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/what-is-animation-nodes-addon-used-for

Comment: https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Qcbbbc/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Animation Nodes is unrelated to the *Everything Nodes* project, even though it's also developed by Jacques Lucke. One of the next big projects will be the replacement of the particle system with [particle nodes](https://developer.blender.org/T73324). More information about the nodes project can be found in the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Nodes) (although I'm not sure if all the information are still up to date).

Comment: @RobertGützkow, experimental version is in the link I've mentioned above.

Comment: @lemon I know, I'm building Blender myself though ;)

Comment: @RobertGützkow Everything Nodes is still very far way, that is probably the closest functional equivalent we will have for quite a while

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I just wanted to point out the difference, since a lot of people seem to mix up the two projects.