# Freestyle: control the Thickness of stroked curve using Radius?

Tags: bezier-curves, freestyle, 2d

*(My english isn't very good, do not hesitate to edit my question)*

I'm currently searching the best way to draw some 2D filled shape using Blender.

For example:

[image]

*This image is a render from Freestyle, the variable stroke width is automatically generated which isn't what I want.*

For the moment, I've found some interesting methods. One of them consists to play with a Bezier Curve in 3D mode that is extruded a little bit (with Tilt at 90°) then I can use `ALT+S` for change the radius of my extrusion. I really like that way of working and it give me that kind of result which is good:

[image]
[image]

The Problem is that I can't easily fill the shapes...
Lets see with this example:
[image]

If I want to fill that shape, I need to:

1. Duplicate my Bezier curve
2. Change the Z position of the duplicated curve to put it behind the original shape.
3. Change its mode to 2D so as fill it.
4. And finally, change its material to the color I want.

[image]

That's a bit annoying to do and when there is a lot of elements on my stage, it becomes a mess, even using Groups.

It would be easier to use Freestyle for that, but how could I control manually the thickness of the stroke like I do with those bezier curve when I'm changing the Radius ? Does a similar way exists (like weight for example) ?

I searched for a modifier of Freestyle Lineset but no luck. I've saw that it is possible to use Python, do you think it is possible to use that mode ? I tried a few, but the data input don't seems aware of a parameter like the Radius of the vertex...

Comment: You don't have to [tilt your curve nor make it 3D](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y), just use a [flat bevel object as described](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/planar-curve-with-width)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Planar curve with width](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/planar-curve-with-width)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The example you show in your answer don't seems to provide a way to have a variable stroke width around the path :/  I'm wrong ? also it seems even less convenient to use, I rather prefer to use my curve solution. But by the way, the object of my question is to control manually the stroke width of the FreeStyle render, by, for example, changing the weight or the radius of a bezier, that would be neat !

Comment: Why not? What happens when you use [curve radius](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale)?

Comment: Ok, it is possible to have a variable stroke width I get it but in that case I cant have a filled shape. You understand my problem ? I want filled shape with a color with a border having a different color and a variable stroke width

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I edited my question, hope it clearer, I think it's not a duplicate at all

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos could you remove your "possible duplicate", please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animation Nodes can be used here. Essentially, if you add a 2D curve and copy the 3D spline to it using this simple node tree, you will get what you need:

[image: Node Tree]

It also works for multiple splines:

[image: Node Tree]

But what if we have multiple spline objects? In this case we append all splines from all objects into a single list and use it instead, and the 3D spline objects can be sourced from a blender object group that the user will add:

[image: Node Tree]

What if we want the fill objects(2D Curves) to be separate objects so that we can add different materials for instance. In this case, the 2D curves can be dynamically generated using the *Instancer Node*:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Cracked it! :D.. I feel I should delete my answer, since it missed the point of the OP..

Comment: @RobinBetts I never knew freestyle could do that, so your answer taught me something new. Better leave the answer anyway.

Comment: wow , it really looks like the answer I'm seeking for, but don't know the animation nodes, never heard about it, it is blender vanilla or an addon ?

Comment: @snoobdogg It is an addon, see [What is Animation Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/what-is-animation-nodes-addon-used-for)

Comment: ok I was able to recreate your firsts programs and it work like a charm, I've just an hardtime with your Loop with Invoke Subprogram. I can find 'Create Spline List' but not 'Spline List'. Also I didn't found the iterator you use for have Source / Target.

Comment: Update: Source and Target are Object List Iterator that you renamed right ? I think your answer is awesome but need more details

Comment: your last patch works like a charm, I also added an Object Transform Output  after Target to ensure that 2D curve is always behind the 3D one: ) thank you!

Comment: @snoobdogg The *Spline List* is not a node, but a generator, you can add it by pressing the plus button at the lower left corner of the Loop Input node and searching for *spline*, check the documentation on [loops](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/loop.html). You are right about the Source and Target.

Answer (score 5):

There is a modifier in Freestyle which will let you do this:

in the Freestyle Line Style for your current line set, select 'Thickness' and assign an 'Along Stroke' modifier.

In the modifier, set the mapping to 'Curve', and , probably, the blend method of the modifier to 'Multiply' of some base thickness value of your stroke.

[image]

You can now click on the curve to create control points you can manipulate by dragging, to control the thickness of the stroke along its length.

It's easier to do this in the  Blender Internal renderer, where you can see the stroke reasonably interactively in the Rendered mode of the 3D View. There's nothing to stop you switching to Cycles when you have your strokes set.

There is (in my system, at least,) an annoyance: sometimes the drop-down menu from the spanner icon on the graph disappears before you can select one of its items. My get-around is to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in and out of rendered mode .. there seems to be a contest for focus.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I already do in the first image of my question. For me that's not ideal at all because it's hard to control the points and because that modifier will be applied to each shape, right ? In fact, appart improve Freestyle with a modifier able to take Radius into account with 2D Bezier Curve, I fear there isn't good solutions to my question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't gather you were using this from the OP. The modifier is applied to the line set, so you  can have a line set for each shape, with different profiles... but yes, it's not the friendliest tool in the world..

Comment: for the moment I combine the Bezier curve technic with freestyle, that's the best solution I've found but it is not very ideal..